# Firebase: Returning a UIImage from URL returns void

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, uiimage

Just wondering if anyone knows why my below code returns void instead of a UIImage.

```
func getImageFromURL(imageURL : String) -> UIImage {
    let ref = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: imageURL)
    ref.getData(maxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("ERROR: Image not downloaded from Firebase.")
        } else {
            print("SUCCESS: Image downloaded from Firebase Storage")
        let img = UIImage(data: data!)
        return img
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't return a value from a method that obtains its value asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks. This explains so much.